# How to support dynamic multiinjection with Ninject, where there may be NO items bound

Tags: ninject

In the following unit tests, `TestDirectRetrieval_WithNoImplementations` and `TestInjection_WithNoImplementations` fail

```
[TestFixture]
public class KernelTests
{
    [Test] //Passes
    public void TestDirectRetrieval_WithMultipleImplementations()
    {
        //Arrange
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<Foo>().ToConstant(new Foo("a"));
        kernel.Bind<Foo>().ToConstant(new Foo("b"));
        //Act + Assert
        Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => kernel.GetAll<Foo>().ToList());
    }

    [Test] //Passes
    public void TestInjection_WithMultipleImplementations()
    {
        //Arrange
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<Foo>().ToConstant(new Foo("a"));
        kernel.Bind<Foo>().ToConstant(new Foo("b"));
        //Act + Assert
        Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => kernel.Get<Bar>());
    }

    [Test] //Fails
    public void TestDirectRetrieval_WithNoImplementations()
    {
        //Arrange
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        //Act + Assert
        Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => kernel.GetAll<Foo>().ToList());
    }

    [Test] //Fails
    public void TestInjection_WithNoImplementations()
    {
        //Arrange
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        //Act + Assert
        Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => kernel.Get<Bar>());
    }

    #region Test helper classes

    class Foo
    {
        public Foo(string someArgThatCantBeAutomaticallyResolvedByNinject){}
    }

    class Bar
    {
        private List<Foo> myFoos;

        public Bar(IEnumerable<Foo> foos)
        {
            myFoos = foos.ToList();
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

In a scenario were someone is binding things to constants / implementations based on some dynamic situation, how can they support the case were nothing is bound at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetAll` is not used by ninject for injection, but as you found out it provides the desired behavior. To enable injection with 0-n semantics I commonly roll my own "collection", an uncomplete / pseudo code version looks like this:

```
class OptionalItems<T> : IEnumerable<T> 
{
   private readonly T[] items;

   public OptionalItems(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot)
   {
       this.items = resolutionRoot.TryGetAll(T).ToArray();
   }

   public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
       return this.items.GetEnumerator();
   }
}
```

Now inject `OptionalItems` instead of `IEnumerable<T>` or `IList<T>`.
For testability-reasons it might make sense to create an interface for `OptionalItems`: `public interface IOperationalItems<T> : IEnumerable<T>` and bind that.

Comment: Do you generally just bind a single `IOptionalItems`/`OptionalItems` with an open generic parameter, or one for each optional type?

Comment: And I notice this has the effect of resolving the IEnumerable at the time of resolution. Is this different from the behaviour when injecting an IEnumerable? I found [this](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/issues/128) (maybe your request?) but it seems not to have been implemented. (Obviously Lazy isn't quite the same due to it's 'once only' resolution)

Comment: I usually bind it with an open generic. In case you need specific scoping (`InSingletonScope()`, `InRequestScope()`) for specific types, you might have to create specific bindings, too. Yes issue #128 was created by me. We had a discussion with Remo-Gloor who was a long-time maintainer and driving force behind Ninject, and he himself said that it is dangerous to *not* materialize the `IEnumerable` in the ctor. So the way i've done it is the safe and recommended way to go.